# Tensorflow gpu issues and 'pip uninstall tensorflow' runs indefinitely

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, anaconda3

I am trying to get my gpu working with tensorflow. It won't work no matter what I do, I have everything installed, reinstalled, repaired, everything. My friend also did everything as I did and got it working by running `pip uninstall tensorflow` then running `pip install tensorflow-gpu`. The issue is that for me, running `pip uninstall tensorflow` runs indefinitely, not doing anything in console, nor giving any error message. I've had it run for at least an hour before giving up and still nothing. Ive tried reinstalling it via pip install, I've tried manually uninstalling then installing tensorflow-gpu both via pip install [notice the command is running (top right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkX5k.png)

I can't find a solution anywhere, I have nothing else I think I can do except maybe uninstall everything python related and do a reinstall.

Comment: You should precise your OS, because this is not the same instructions for Linux and Windows. Just saying.

Answer (score 0):

when you are trying to run TensorFlow on the gpu on a pip environment, installing `tensorflow` or `tensorflow-gpu` is not enough because there must be `CUDA` and `cudnn` installed in the computer. 
watch this [video](https://youtu.be/xQVOaTUm9lM) to install `CUDA` and `cudnn`.

Comment: Sorry I did not specify that, I did install both of them. I double checked I did it correctly as well. I have the latest version for everything as well.

Comment: why would you say it is not running in the `gpu`. does it show any error?.